# How to update react state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I want to ask what's the best way to update state, I have some code. I know the code below is not correct as it's setting the state directly.

```
handlexxx = foo => { 
  const foos = [...this.state.foos]; 
  const index = foos.indexOf(foo); 
  foos[index].bar = !foo.bar; 
  this.setState({ foos }); 
};
```

Those two code below which one is better? can some one explain me please!

```
handlexxx = foo => { 
  const foos = [...this.state.foos]; 
  const index = foos.indexOf(foo); 
  foos[index] = { ...foo }; 
  foos[index].bar = !foo.bar; 
  this.setState({ foos }); 
};

handlexxx = foo => { 
  const foos = [...this.state.foos];
  const index = foos.indexOf(foo); 
  foos[index] = { ...foos[index] };
  foos[index].bar = !foos[index].bar;
  this.setState({ foos }); 
};
```

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: How is your `foo`'s shape as an object?

Comment: @devserkan foo is an object foos is an array of objects, foo only contains some basic properties like id, name, isSelected etc

Comment: @AndySong In ReactJS, we often use `Array.prototype.map()` method to implement that kind of updating

Comment: @AndySong what makes you think your state assignment is wrong here? It seems you only need to add Object.assign to avoid mutation...

Comment: @duhaime, does not `Object.assign` or spread syntax make shallow copies? I don't know where do you suggest to use `Object.assign` here but changing nested properties also mutates the original state.

Comment: @devserkan using Object.assign will allow you to avoid mutations. Compare: `var a = [1,2]; b = a; a.push(3); console.log(b);` with `var a = [1,2]; b = Object.assign([], a); a.push(3); console.log(b);` Here Object.assign should be used where the OP is reading from state...

Comment: @duhaime, you are not doing a nested property change in your example. `Object.assign` does not avoid mutation for nested properties. If OP does this: `const foos = Object.assign( {}, state.foos);
  const index = state.foos.findIndex(el => el.id === foo.id );
  foos[index].bar = !foo.bar;  ` they mutate the original state. If I understand you wrong you can explain it of course. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read this closely enough to even see the OP is making nested property changes. I'll post an oldschool response below...

Comment: @duhaime, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `foo` object has an `id` property it is better to use `.map` method and mix this with spread syntax or `Object.assign`, then return the related elements as @Nguyễn Thanh Tú explained. But, if you want to do this with indexes here are the examples.

You can use `findIndex`, not `indexOf`. Since `indexOf` just look for a value, `findIndex` accepts a function. Find the index of the item, map the array, then if index matches do the change if it does not match return the unrelated item.

```js
state = {
  foos: [
    { id: 1, bar: true },
    { id: 2, bar: false },
    { id: 3, bar: false },
  ],
};

const foo = { id: 2, bar: false };

const handleState = foo => {
  const index = state.foos.findIndex(el => el.id === foo.id );
  const newFoos = state.foos.map( ( foo, i ) => {
    if ( i !== index ) { return foo };
    return { ...foo, bar: !foo.bar };
  })
  
  console.log( newFoos );
}

handleState(foo);
```

Second one. Here, we are using `Object.assign` in a tricky way. Instead of mapping the array we use `Object.assign` and change the item using its index.

```js
state = {
  foos: [
    { id: 1, bar: true },
    { id: 2, bar: false },
    { id: 3, bar: false },
  ],
};

const foo = { id: 2, bar: false };

const handleState2 = foo => {
  const index = state.foos.findIndex(el => el.id === foo.id );
  const newFoos = Object.assign( [], state.foos, { [index]: { ...foo, bar: !foo.bar } });
  
  console.log( newFoos );
}

handleState2(foo);
```

Third one. Without an index, with only `.map` and using directly the `id` property. We don't need to find an index here, we are just checking with the `id` property to find the right item.

```js
state = {
  foos: [
    { id: 1, bar: true },
    { id: 2, bar: false },
    { id: 3, bar: false },
  ],
};

const foo = { id: 2, bar: false };

const handleState3 = foo => {
  const newFoos = state.foos.map( el => {
    if ( el.id !== foo.id ) { return el };
    return { ...el, bar: !el.bar };
  })
  
  console.log( newFoos );
}

handleState3( foo );
```

Comment: so do u mean `findIndex` is faster than `indexOf` as  `indexOf` checks all the properties whereas `findIndex` only check one value?

Comment: Problem is not the speed here, `indexOf` does not work on objects as you thought. It can't compare all the properties like that. `indexOf` just search for an item in an array. See the [related documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: oh I see, thanks, so if I have id in the object, I do not really need to find out the index. it seems like extra work.

Comment: Of course, this is why I tried to provide all the alternatives. As you can see in @duhaime's answer there are more alternatives. Just examine all of them for cons and pros. But, at the end of the day accept the answer which suits you more. I would say upvote all of them for the efforts but I know your reputation probably is not enough for that right now :D

Comment: one thing I want to ask is that for this code `const newFoos = state.foos.map( el => {
    if ( el.id !== foo.id ) { return el };
    return { ...foo, bar: !foo.bar };
  })`  `bar:!foo.bar` can I use `bar:!el.bar`? any suggestion?

Comment: or there is no much difference?

Comment: It does the same thing @AndySong since in this condition (where `id`'s match), `el` is `foo`. But I don't prefer using like this. I always think `el` is the mapped object from the array and `foo` is my target. I do things according to my target. But again, this is only a logical approach.

Comment: As I said it does the same thing since `el` is `foo` in the matched if block :) But if you do this at least use it like this `return { ...el, bar: !el.bar }; }` :) Maybe this is better since we are playing the mapped targets here. Let me change my answer according to that.

Comment: yes, I think now is better, very logical to me. we just use `foo.id` to the item in the original array, and return each item from the original array (do the changes that we need to do) then map each into a new array. is it correct? what I understand?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We map the original array, if the item is not our target we don't do anything, just return it. If the item is matched with our target (comparing the `id`s), we do the changes and return the changed item.

Comment: great very clear now, thank u very much. have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Array.prototype.map()` method, like this:

```
handlexxx = foo => { 
  const foos = this.state.foos.map(f => {
    if(foo.id === f.id) return {...f, bar: !f.bar};   // assume that the element has an identifier id
    return f;
  })
  this.setState({ foos }); 
};
```

For short, using `ternary operator` instead of `if-else` statement

```
handlexxx = foo => { 
  const foos = this.state.foos.map(f => foo.id === f.id ? {...f, bar: !f.bar} : f
  this.setState({ foos }); 
};
```

Comment: @AndySong you might consider accepting or upvoting it :)

Comment: They can't because of the reputation :) But hey, I have some to upvote :D

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I am very sorry, I can only choose one answer. I will upvote ur one after I got enough reputation.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that, I just forgot about the reputation requirement for upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

One classic way to avoid mutations even for complex nested objects is to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(COMPLICATED_OBJECT))`. This will return a representation of your object that has no reference to the original object, so you can mutate the copy without affecting the original:

```
var foos = [
  { id: 1, bar: false },
  { id: 2, bar: false },
  { id: 3, bar: false },
]

var foo = foos[0];

var _foos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foos)).map(f => {
  if (f.id === foo.id) f.bar = !foo.bar;
  return f;
});
```

If you run this, you'll see `foos` is unchanged but `_foos` is updated

At the end of the day, you might want to think about which solution you find most readable, and which solution other developers on your team might find most readable. If you have to return to this code in 3 years, you'll want to be able to read the code off the page without any head scratching.

Comment: Good alternative. Just one catch I think, here object should be serializable, if not we lose the unserializable parts.